# Nearby localities in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, location, associations

I have a model called Locality, which is basically a city (or a suburb within a big city).

Each Locality has a short list of the Localities which are adjacent - this is to help in searching.

I have read dozens of posts on here regarding self-referential has_many, :through associations and so on, but I'm still having trouble figuring this out.

Essentially what I'd like to end up with is:

```
l = Locality.find(1)
n = l.nearby_localities
# n should now hold a list of Locality ids
```

What's the best way for this to be done?

Comment: This article explains how to implement a self referential many-to-many: http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/self-referential-many-to-many-relations-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you determine `nearby_localities`?

Actually, you could just have it a simple method.

```
class Localities < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Previous Code ...

  def nearby_localities
    # Implementation here.
  end

end
```

Keep it simple!

Comment: `nearby_localities` is a static, painstakingly compiled list of Locality ids. Given your answer, and my newness to Ruby/Rails, my instinct would be to save a comma-separated list of ids in a column, and retrieve and parse them into an array of other Localities with that method. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @CalebFidecaro: Do you want to query for nearby locations? If so, a comma seperated list is a bad idea. You'd better store the relation between locations in a seperate database table.

Comment: Yep that would work. You can serialize the locality ids as an array. Just remember that the type of the column should be `text`. For more info, check this out: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Comment: @Mischa The `nearby_localities` field holds an array of Locality ids - these are not dynamic in any way, they are literally a hand-built list of Localities that could be considered "nearby", according to local knowledge. For example a Localilty could be geographically close to another, but across the harbour, making it not "nearby" in the sense that I want.

Comment: @BenjaminTan Thanks a lot for that - much easier solution than I was cooking up.

Comment: @CalebFidecaro It's not a question of being dynamic or not. It's a question of wanting the query the field. Something like this: `l.nearby_localities.where(...)` doesn't work on a serialized field. If you think you want to query the `nearby_localities` in the future, you'd better implement it differently now. If you are sure you only use it for displaying the nearby localities then it's fine to serialize them.